Apgdiff doesn't retain "<schema_name>.<tablename>" format in the diff
I am using apgdiff tool to generate a diff between two sql dump files.
CREATE TABLE abc.xyz (...)
In my final diff file, the tool adds a SET search_path=abc,pg_catalog;
I would expect it to not play with search_path but to retain the <schema_name>.<tablename> format in the diff file as this is what my dump files have. Am I missing something? Is there a way to do this?

Did you ask the author?
